# Is there a way to export data stored in a table of Cloud SQL instance?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-sql

Please suggest if there is a way to export the complete data present in the table of cloud SQL instance.

I have tried following options but neither of the worked.

1. Export from SQuirrel Client: Since there is larger set of data present in the table. We encounter time out trying to load data under tab "Content" and hence cannot proceed further to get the option of export(on right click).
2. [Importing and Exporting Data](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/advanced_tasks.html#importexport) provides the dump, but i need to export only data present in table.

Please also suggest if it possible through apps script as the other functionality is coded in Apps Script.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to write a simple Apps Script that takes the data in a table and creates/updates a spreadsheet with it.

Learn more about Apps Script Cloud SQL/JDBC support [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/jdbc).

Sample function that exports a table with 2 columns to a spreadsheet. You can improve the logic here to your needs.

```
function read() {
var conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection("jdbc:google:rdbms://<myinstance>/mysql");
  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  var rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from animals");

  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.create('data export');
  var cell = doc.getRange('a1');
  var row = 0;
  while(rs.next()) {
    cell.offset(row, 0).setValue(rs.getString(1));
    cell.offset(row, 1).setValue(rs.getString(2));
    row++;
  }
  rs.close();
  stmt.close();
  conn.close();
}
```

Comment: :I have to export data(may be in a csv etc) so that it can be loaded to other database. The logic shared will fetch and write data on spreadsheet.

Comment: In addition to that since the data is large if I go with the above code I may encounter spreadsheet limit warning in an attempt to write fetched data on spreadsheet. Also, do we need to publish spreadsheet if we use method create('Data export')?

Comment: @Arun `setValue` cell by cell on a loop isn't really an example of [good practice](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices#OptimizeScripts). Specially when the loop is potentially big. I think we (that are reference on this) should not sow such code examples :-/

Comment: User1868355, you can always create a CSV file and write it to your Drive or mail it out as an attachment.

Comment: I tried converting resultset to csv and storing it in drive. I worked well for about 500 rows but then got "Exceeded maximum execution time" error when rows were more than 500. I am even using Limit clause while fetching the records but still encountering the time out. Please suggest.

Comment: @ArunNagarajan I tried fetching the data, created csv out of it. Now in am attempt to create a file using(DocsList.createFile("TestExport.csv", fileContentToExport);) I get error "File exceeds the maximum size". There are around 36 columns and 1,50,000 records in the table. I would like to have all my data in one file and multiple files are not requirement. Can you please suggest alternate. Also, what is maximum file size allowed.

Comment: The maximum file size is 10mb via the API for now. Another alternative is write to Fusion Tables which scales well and then downloading the file from there.. bit of a stretch but might be worth it. There is video that talks about using Fusion Tables API from Apps Script - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eHM0zbUE5A0

Comment: @ArunNagarajan Thanks Arun for your suggestion. Fusion table will not work as per the requirement since, it would be nothing but getting data out from one table and putting it in another table. Coming back to my earlier post, Since my data was larger than 10mb, i am trying to create new files and writing smaller data chunk in newly created file. But then i get error. I have put  Utilities.sleep(8000) after the createFile statement. Still below error is coming.   "Execution failed: Service invoked too many times in a short time: driveWriteVolume rateMax. Try Utilities.sleep(1000) between calls"

Comment: It's better if you roll that into a separate question regarding writing large files in Apps Script.

Comment: @ArunNagarajan: As per the suggested link below, I was trying to access the export functionality. I was playing around the code, but have no idea which all code snippet is required and how to perform oAuth in Apps Script. Please provide your suggestions.I have also turned on the service in script editor "Upgrade authorization Experience".

Comment: @ArunNagarajan: I an getting below error:Exception: Request failed for returned code 401. Server response: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "authError", "message": "Invalid Credentials", "locationType": "header", "location": "Authorization" } ], "code": 401, "message": "Invalid Credentials" } }

Answer (score 0):

The Cloud SQL admin API is available now. You can use it to export specific tables.
See https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/admin-api/v1beta1/instances/export.

Comment: Can you please share how I can form the JSON in Apps SCript. I am encountering error Exception::Exception: Request failed for  returned code 401. Server response: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "authError",
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Invalid Credentials"
 }
}